# MySQL: Return list of values in one table conditional on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to create a view of student ID numbers that are active (paying) members.

Student numbers are stored in a table called `usermeta` like so:

```
user_id          meta_key          meta_value
---------------------------------------------
      1         studentid                1234
```

Whether the person is a member is stored in the `posts` table (Woocommerce/Wordpress setup...):

```
post_author         post_status
-------------------------------
          1          wcm_active
```

`user_id` and `post_author` are the unique IDs identifying each member/user.

I know I can return a list of ID numbers like so:

`SELECT meta_value FROM usermeta WHERE meta_key = "studentid"`

I just can't quite figure out how to make it conditional on if `post_status = wcm-active`

If anyone has some input it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can place a join between user_id and post_author to get all the student ids whose status is wcm_active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT meta_value 
FROM usermeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'studentid'
AND user_id IN (SELECT post_author FROM posts WHERE post_status = 'wcm_active')
```

Comment: Aha! I had something similar actually, but I was not sure about how to format the `AND` correctly, of course it is so simple... 

Thank you very much